# How to link a trail to functions by partial name in CDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

[The original code](https://github.com/linz/geostore/blob/a5241fee707a8b3700b24b96182153b8dbdb4d8b/infrastructure/constructs/api.py#L111-L140) created a bucket and trail in a single stack per deployment, and linked them to a function in the same stack:

```
trail_bucket = aws_s3.Bucket(
    self,
    "cloudtrail-bucket",
    access_control=aws_s3.BucketAccessControl.PRIVATE,
    block_public_access=aws_s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
    auto_delete_objects=True,
    removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
)
trail = aws_cloudtrail.Trail(
    self,
    "cloudtrail",
    send_to_cloud_watch_logs=True,
    bucket=trail_bucket,
    cloud_watch_log_group=aws_logs.LogGroup(self, "api-user-log"),
    removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
)
trail.add_lambda_event_selector(
    [import_status_endpoint_lambda],
    include_management_events=False,
)
```

This has become a problem for CI, since we regularly hit the limit of five trails per account (all CI deployments are to the same account). So I'm looking into the possibility of pulling the trail into its own stack and linking it to the relevant functions via a wildcard. Basically, I want to log any events from ARNs matching `arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*import-status`. Is this possible?

The documentation for [`Trail.add_event_selector`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudtrail/Trail.html#aws_cdk.aws_cloudtrail.Trail.add_event_selector) speaks of the data resource values as being specifically ARNs, and [`DataResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_DataResource.html) seems to indicate that my only choices are

- log events for *all* functions (too much) or
- log events for *a specific ARN* (unknown at deployment time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudTrail has [Advanced Event Selectors](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/optimize-aws-cloudtrail-costs-using-advanced-event-selectors/) like `EndsWith` to filter ARNs. This fits your use case, where you want a shared Trail for all Lambda ARNs ending with `import-status`.

OK, but how do you set Advanced Event Selectors with the CDK? Unfortunately, the CloudFormation [AWS::CloudTrail::Trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudtrail-trail.html) resource (= CDK L1 [CfnTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudtrail.CfnTrail.html) construct, which underlies the L2 [Trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudtrail.Trail.html)) appears not to support them in the [eventSelectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudtrail.CfnTrail.EventSelectorProperty.html) prop. Fortunately, CDK (and CloudFormation) has [Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) to plug such gaps.

In your new `trail_stack`, create a Trail and a [AWSCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) construct, which makes arbitrary SDK calls.  It will call the [PutEventsSelectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_PutEventSelectors.html#API_PutEventSelectors_RequestSyntax) API on your Trail, setting the Advanced Event Selectors.  It will be called once, on resource create:

```py
# trail_stack.py
aws_custom = cr.AwsCustomResource(self, "aws-custom-advanced-selectors",
    on_create=cr.AwsSdkCall(
        service="CloudTrail",
        action="putEventSelectors",
        parameters= parameters: {
          TrailName: my_trail.trail_arn,
          AdvancedEventSelectors: [
            {
              Name: 'Log import-status lambdas only',
              FieldSelectors: [
                { Field: 'eventCategory', Equals: ['Data'] },
                { Field: 'resources.type', Equals: ['AWS::Lambda::Function'] },
                {
                  Field: 'resources.ARN',
                  EndsWith: ['import-status'],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        physical_resource_id=cr.PhysicalResourceId.of("aws-custom-advanced-selectors")
    ),
    policy=cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_sdk_calls(
        resources=my_trail.trail_arn
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For reference, here's the [resulting PR](https://github.com/linz/geostore/pull/1477) and [CDK issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19398).